# how can i wrap each of li element with p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

i have an structure dom :

```
    <div class="reditor_body">
      <p>saeed<p>
      <p>aghaebrahimain</p>
    </div>
```

when i was selected the p tag and click the ordered list button , 
the structure becomes as following :

```
<div class="reditor_body">
<ol>
    <li>saeed<li>
    <li>aghaebrahimain</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

my problem is , when i select the each of the li or both and click the ordered list button again , the structure becames:

```
<div class="reditor_body">
     saeed
     aghaebrahimain
</div>
```

while i want the following structure :

```
 <div class="reditor_body">
    <p>saeed<p>
    <p>aghaebrahimain</p>
 </div>
```

how can i resolved this problem with javascript or jquery like ckeditor or tinymce ?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redhat2/veh6e/2/)

Comment: Finally what you need?

Comment: where's your jquery code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `.unwrap()` the ol and use `.replaceWith()` in jquery for replace the p tag instead of li

```
$(".reditor_body ol").click(function() {

$(".reditor_body ol li").unwrap("ol").replaceWith(function() {
    return $("<p></p>").append($(this).html());
});

});
```

[***`Fiddle`***](http://jsfiddle.net/JJLqu/1/)

Comment: when i select two li and click , then one li transform to p tag and another Remain to be li tag , an ol tag removed , where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code to remember removed `<p>` tag (in case there may be any other element instead of `<p>`) and than when removing list elements wrap text with pre-saved element (for example same `<p>` tag